# pickle.loads does not return the same data dumped

Tags: python, pickle

PolicyModule is a class created by me.

When I try to dump/load an instance of it I do not get in return the same data:

```
module = PolicyModule(new.name,new.domain,decomposed_module[switch][port])
module.install()
modules[new.name] = module
print 'POLICY TO DUMP'
print modules[new.name].isInstalled()
print modules[new.name].name
print modules[new.name].domain
print modules[new.name].action
print modules[new.name].policy  
print '\n'
msg = pickle.dumps(modules[new.name],-1)
x = pickle.loads(msg)
print 'POLICY LOADED'
print x.isInstalled()
print x.name
print x.domain
print x.action
print x.policy 
print '\n'
```

This is what is printed:

```
POLICY TO DUMP
True
routing
match: ('dstip', 10.0.0.1)
parallel:
    sequential:
        match: ('switch', 2) ('dstip', 10.0.0.2)
        fwd 1
    sequential:
        match: ('switch', 2) ('dstip', 10.0.0.3)
        fwd 2
sequential:
    match: ('dstip', 10.0.0.1)
    parallel:
        sequential:
            match: ('switch', 2) ('dstip', 10.0.0.2)
            fwd 1
        sequential:
            match: ('switch', 2) ('dstip', 10.0.0.3)
            fwd 2

POLICY LOADED
True
routing
match: ('dstip', 10.0.0.1)
drop
identity
```

**Note well**: match, sequential, fwd and parallel are instances of others classes.

For each class, I set the *setstate* and *getstate* methods as following:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    odict = self.__dict__.copy() # copy the dict since we change it
    return odict

def __setstate__(self, dict):
    self.__dict__.update(dict)
```

It think that the problem is here:

```
class sequential(CombinatorPolicy):

def __new__(self, policies=[]):
    if len(policies) == 0:
        return identity
    else:
        rv = super(sequential, self).__new__(sequential, policies)
        rv.__init__(policies)
        return rv
```

and here:

```
class parallel(CombinatorPolicy):

def __new__(self, policies=[]):
    # Hackety hack.
    if len(policies) == 0:
        return drop
    else:
        rv = super(parallel, self).__new__(parallel, policies)
        rv.__init__(policies)
        return rv
```

because I always get a *drop* instead of a *parallel* instance, and an *identity* instead of a *sequential*.
It's like the *setdate* method passes an empty list to the *new* method.

Comment: What type of objects are the `action` and `policy`?

Comment: The `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods are redundant; that's what already happens. The comment `# copy the dict since we change it` suggests that there is more going on in that method, however.

Comment: @BrenBarn In this case, action is an instance of the _parallel_ class, policy is an instance of the _sequential_ class, instead. They are both classes of the pyretic library.

Comment: @danieledc: And are they picklable?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Therefore, should I have to define __setstate__ and __getstate__ only for the _PolicyModule_ class? Or not even for that class?

Comment: I don't know anything about your classes, so this is hard to generalize.

Comment: @BrenBarn How can I prove it?

Comment: @danieledc: You could try creating an instance of just one of those classes (i.e., by themselves, without using your `PolicyModule` at all) and see if you can pickle/unpickle them.  If you can't, that's probably the problem.

Comment: @BrenBarn The problem is there, actually. Please, give a look to my updated topic.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself.

I just forgot to define **getnewargs** methods in both *parallel* and *sequential* classes.

More info [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-normal-class-instances).